# sed/awk to double space file

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file with blank lines and I need to double space the lines in the file. Meaning I need a blank line between two lines with text in it. Can you show me an easy way to do it with awk and/or sed

Comment: What do you want to do with the existing blank lines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
sed '/^$/d' fileName | sed G
```

Answer (score 7):

using `sed`

```
$ sed G input.txt | cat -s
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming:
 
1. You want to do this in just SED
 
2. You want to do it all in one pass
 
3. Some of your "blank" lines might contain tabs|spaces
  
4. The current spacing is non-uniform (0, 1, or more blanks after each line)
 
5. You want to end up with uniform double-spacing
 
Try this:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
/^[ \t]*$/d
/^..*$/a\
```

The first line says:      
                      If you see a "blank line", delete it.
The second line says: If you see a non-blank line, append a line after it.

Answer (score 1):

A very quick way using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed '/^$/d;G'
```

This deletes all empty lines using the command `/^$/d` and appends the content of the hold space (which is empty) to the pattern space with a newline in between (`G`).

A very quick way is using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";ORS=OFS="\n\n"}{$1=$1}1'
```

How does this work:

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) knowns the concept records (which is by default lines) and you can define a record by its record separator `RS`. If you set the value of `RS` to an empty string, it will match any multitude of empty lines as a record separator. The value `ORS` is the output record separator. It states which separator should be printed between two consecutive records. This is set to two <newline> characters.
This, however, does not solve the problem when you have a multi-line record. So for this, we define fields (by default words). The field separator `FS` is defined as a single <newline> character such that each field represents a line. And the output field-separator is defined as two <newline> characters. We convert `FS` into `OFS` by reassigning the first field to itself `{$1=$1}` Finally, the statement `1` is a shorthand for `{print $0}` which prints the current record followed by the output record-separator `ORS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.txt
test
tset 2
test 3
test 4
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ sed 's/\(.*\)/\1\n/' test.txt
test

tset 2

test 3

test 4
```

Sai's `sed G test.txt` works also, but I have no idea how.

Comment: 'how': in a first pass, you delete all empty lines (assuming lines do not contain white space); in a second pass, you append the content of hold space (==an empty line as we put nothing in it) to each line, then print it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
awk '{print $0 "\n"}' fileName
```

Comment: This was nice.  I needed to double space by adding blank line BEFORE each line in the source, so simply did `awk '{print "\n" $0 }'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the existing blank lines intact:

```
awk '
    prev && $0 {print ""}
    {print; prev = $0}
'
```

The first test will only be true if both the previous line and the current line are non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:
 
1. You want to do this in just AWK
 
2. You want to do it all in one pass
 
3. Some of your "blank" lines might contain tabs|spaces
  
4. The current spacing is non-uniform (0, 1, or more blanks after each line)
 
5. You want to end up with uniform double-spacing

Try this:

```
awk '$0 !~ /^[ \t]*$/ { print $0, "\n" }' <file>
```

Breaking this up,
 
 The part before the curly bracket says:    Match only non-blank lines
 
 The part within the curly brackets says:   Print this line and append one more (a blank one)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/.*/&\n/p'
```

`&` and `\n` should work I guess

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
 # double space a file
 $ awk '1;{print ""}' file
```

Another way

```
 # or like this
 $ awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n"};1' file
```

[Awk one-liners](http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt)